# How to change NSScrollView font from XCode 4 Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder, nsscrollview

Does anyone know how to change font in `NSScrollView` using XCode 4 Interface Builder?

Thanks for the help.

PS: This is for Mac OS development. The font panel for iPhone ScrollView can be seen in Attributes Inspector (as pointed by Khrisna below), but not for MacOS development.

Answer (score -1):

NSScrollView class is composed of  NSClipView and NSScroller classes. I guess we NSScrollView does not have a property through which we can change the FONT of the text to be written.

We change the font for the text in either UITextField or UILabel. So, when use use these in the ScrollView, we can change their font as:

```
 1. PRogrammatically:
    myTextFied.font = [UIFont fontWithName:<#(NSString *)#> size:<#(CGFloat)#>];
    or
    myTextFied.font = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:<#(NSString *)#>];

 2. Using Interface Builder:
    You can set your font in the Attributes Inspector.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm currently developing for Mac application, and I could not see the font panel in Attributes Inspector. It's there though for iPhone project. Any idea? :)